# How do I add linebreaks in a InnerHTML javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering how I could add line breaks  on in something like this.

```html
document.getElementById("Lyrics").innerHTML = ("Cras sed gravida augue,  in elementum velit. Proin vel libero gravida, luctus elit at, auctor mauris. Morbi ultricies auctor blandit. Praesent eget leo ac ipsum condimentum finibus vitae ac nisi. Suspendisse a nisi sed metus commodo sagittis. Nulla varius aliquam nisi, sit amet mattis elit malesuada ac. Maecenas vulputate massa velit, quis volutpat nunc fringilla quis. Cras eu ex sed erat venenatis rutrum. Suspendisse ac dui metus. Sed cursus sodales quam sed luctus. Pellentesque magna quam, vulputate non nulla eget, aliquam ultricies lacus. Maecenas vehicula id quam a interdum. Donec laoreet nec mauris at bibendum. Donec molestie condimentum ullamcorper. ");
```

I'm doing this for a beginner school project so I'm planning on putting lyrics instead.

Comment: Have you tried adding `<br>` in your string?

Comment: As it was mentioned, using <br> will do the trick. If you want to add breaks inside a <textarea> or alert message, you have to use \n instead

Comment: Also, note that the parenthesis around the string are not required and not commonly used

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<br>` between each sentence or wrap each of them in `<p>`. You can also add `\n` if the containing element is a `<pre>` or uses [`white-space: pre` or `white-space: pre-line`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):

```js
document.getElementById("container1").innerHTML = "Cras sed gravida augue, in elementum velit.<br>Proin vel libero gravida, luctus elit at, auctor mauris.<br>Morbi ultricies auctor blandit. Praesent eget leo ac ipsum condimentum finibus vitae ac nisi.";

document.getElementById("container2").innerHTML = "<p>Cras sed gravida augue, in elementum velit.</p><p>Proin vel libero gravida, luctus elit at, auctor mauris.</p><p>Morbi ultricies auctor blandit. Praesent eget leo ac ipsum condimentum finibus vitae ac nisi.</p>";

document.getElementById("container3").innerHTML = "Cras sed gravida augue, in elementum velit.\nProin vel libero gravida, luctus elit at, auctor mauris.\nMorbi ultricies auctor blandit. Praesent eget leo ac ipsum condimentum finibus vitae ac nisi.";

document.getElementById("container4").innerHTML = "Cras sed gravida augue, in elementum velit.\nProin vel libero gravida, luctus elit at, auctor mauris.\nMorbi ultricies auctor blandit. Praesent eget leo ac ipsum condimentum finibus vitae ac nisi.";
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

div, pre {
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#container3 {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1"></div>
<div id="container2"></div>
<div id="container3"></div>
<pre id="container4"></pre>
```

Comment: Okay that was easier than I though

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to rendering the html itself in multiple lines, you can use the html 
 in between parts of the sentence.

For Example,

```
document.getElementById("Lyrics").innerHTML = ("Cras sed gravida augue,  <br /> in elementum velit. <br />Proin vel libero gravida, luctus elit at, auctor mauris. Morbi ultricies auctor blandit. Praesent eget leo ac ipsum condimentum finibus vitae ac nisi. Suspendisse a nisi sed metus commodo sagittis. Nulla varius aliquam nisi, sit amet mattis elit malesuada ac. <br />Maecenas vulputate massa velit, quis volutpat nunc fringilla quis. Cras eu ex sed erat venenatis rutrum. Suspendisse ac dui metus. Sed cursus sodales quam sed luctus. Pellentesque magna quam, vulputate non nulla eget, aliquam ultricies lacus. Maecenas vehicula id quam a interdum. Donec laoreet nec mauris at bibendum. Donec molestie condimentum ullamcorper. ");
```

You can also use any other html tags you'd like within the quotation marks. Hope that helps!